# Create a view for the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am reading "Pragmatic Agile Web Development with Rails (2th ed)" and trying examples from this book.  But when I am trying one of examples I have got error.

So:

- I have created a model for a product

  ```
  ruby script/generate model product
  ```

  Filled the fields:

  ```
  class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
     create_table :products do |t|
       t.column :title, :string
       t.column :description, :text
       t.column :image_url, :string
     end
   end

   def self.down
    drop_table :products
   end
  end
  ```

  Generated the DB:

  ```
  rake db:migrate
  ```
- Next I have creaded the view:

  ```
  ruby script/generate controller admin
  ```

  Added line to the view:

  ```
  class AdminController < ApplicationController
    scaffold :product
  end
  ```

  - Have runned the server and have got error:

    http://localhost:3000/admin

    ```
    undefined method `scaffold' for AdminController:Class
    ```

I have googled and found this solution:

```
ruby script/generate scaffold product title:string description:text image_url:string
```

But I am not sure that it is a right way.  What is the 'true way' to create a view for the product table ?

Comment: Scaffold generator can be used as a base for future development, not only views but also models and controllers. It will create all MVC structure of the particular model. When you're doing first steps with rails this seems to be the best solution. Then you'll decide if it suits you or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scaffold` method has been removed from Rails since about 2.0 version. Since that time, one should use the generator for scaffolding.

Answer (score 1):

To create an example you'd just run

```
ruby script/generate scaffold Product title:string description:text image_url:string
```

This will generate MVC structure for products

Comment: commas are not needed here. see the author's working solution.